# moderncv modify right margin or length of cvitem

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to edit my resume, and I have trouble managing the spacing on the cvitem. I'd like it to be of a shorter length, more specifically I want the line ending to be less than the other elements.

[image]

Here I have an itemize inside the cvitem. Basically I want the entire cvitem to be of shorter length. I tried modifying some of the moderncv classes, but to no avail. Help appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: The code here

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

    \usepackage{verbatim}

    % moderncv themes
    \moderncvtheme[blue]{banking}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
    %\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

    % character encoding
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

    % adjust the page margins
    \usepackage[scale=0.93]{geometry}
    .....
    \begin{document}
    ....
    \cvitem{Projects}{\begin{itemize} 
    \item \textbf{Porting packages to Image Packaging System in OpenSolaris} \newline{} Sun Microsystems Internship. Ported applications such as Parcellite, VLC to the IPS in OpenSolaris. Published in Fibonacci, Vol 1, SF-FOSS, IIITM, Gwalior, India \end{itemize}}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `\cventry` so that its content is inside a `minipage`. Put these lines in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\begin{minipage}[t]{15cm}\hintstyle{#2}: }{#3}\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

and adjust `15cm` to your needs.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
 \usepackage{verbatim}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[blue]{banking}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.93]{geometry}

\firstname{John}\familyname{Doe}

\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\begin{minipage}[t]{15cm}\hintstyle{#2}: }{#3}\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cvitem{Projects}{\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Porting packages to Image Packaging System in OpenSolaris} \newline{} Sun Microsystems Internship. Ported applications such as Parcellite, VLC to the IPS in OpenSolaris. Published in Fibonacci, Vol 1, SF-FOSS, IIITM, Gwalior, India \end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]